# OneNote "My Add-ins" is disabled

Tags: office-js, office-addins, onenote

I'm trying to add a new Office.js based Add-in to OneNote 2016. Unfortunately the "My Add-ins" button is grayed out:

[image]

I have confirmed that all the different options inside the Trust Center are configured correctly and "My Add-ins" is working property in both Word and Excel.

Anyone have an idea what may be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently only the OneNote Online supports Office.js Add-ins. From the [documentation](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/onenote/onenote-add-ins-programming-overview?product=onenote):

> OneNote introduces a JavaScript API for **OneNote Online** add-ins. You can create task pane add-ins, content add-ins, and add-in commands that interact with OneNote objects and connect to web services or other web-based resources.

You can see support by app and platform at [Office Add-in Availability](https://dev.office.com/add-in-availability).

*If you would like to see OneNote add-ins supported on more platforms, I strongly suggest adding this to the [Office UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).*